# Why this condition is not correct in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I have code that returns the following JSON:

```
{"code_retour":-1,"texte_retour":"Le lien de parent\u00e9 est inconnu"}
```

In my JS code, I have this condition which returns `true`:

```
    if (reponse.code_retour != 0) {
```

And this one returns `false`:

```
if (reponse.code_retour == -1) {
```

There is something I'm missing. **Why don't both return true?**

Here is my code for more details :

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: $('#url_for_ajax').val()+'/post_formulaire_responsables_personne',
       data: $('#form_responsable').serialize(),
       success: function(reponse) {

        // reset des erreurs
        $('#form_responsable :input').parent().parent().removeClass('has-error has-feedback');
        $('#form_responsable :input').nextAll('span,small').remove();
        $("#reponse-serveur").hide();
console.log(reponse);           
        // il y a des erreurs dans le formulaire
        if (reponse.code_retour == -1) {
            alert('I am here');             
            var arr = reponse.texte_retour;
            if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(arr)){
                    var errorString = '<ul>';
                    $.each(arr, function(index, value)
                    {
                        if (value.length != 0) {errorString += '<li>' + value + '</li>';}

                        $(':input[name="' + index + '"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error has-feedback');
                        $(':input[name="' + index + '"]').after('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span><small class="text-danger">'+value+'</small>');
                    });
                    errorString += '</ul>';
            }

           $("#reponse-serveur").html(errorString);
           $("#reponse-serveur").show();


           } else {
```

Comment: I bet the value of `code_retour` is different than you think. https://jsfiddle.net/hpen6hen/

Comment: Try  if (reponse.code_retour === -1) {

Comment: Those two different statements are in two different places in your code. Values of variables and object properties can change, so that must be what is happening. Without seeing more of the code, however, it's not possible to say exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @GetApp: Why would that be different? If `=== -1` is true, so is `== -1`. In other words, if `== -1` is `false`, `=== -1` cannot be `true`.

Comment: Did you parse the JSON string?

Comment: When I run your code against the json you've posted, both return true. However I notived you're comparing to `reponse` as opposed to `response` - it might seem silly, but is this a spelling error that's causing this?

Comment: Works just fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/1n0e2v04/ so something in your real code is NOT as you've shown in your question.  I'd suggest you do `console.log(reponse.code_retour);` and then perhaps `console.log(reponse)` to see what you actually have.  These are elementary debugging and problem solving steps which you should learn and use before coming here.

Comment: First just try console.log(response.code_retour) and see what you get

Comment: console log your code_retour before check, it's value is obviously not -1

Comment: I edited the post with more details. Thanks.

Comment: in my console I see -1 for "code_retour". the code sent by the server is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both cases return `true`. [Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/451sLzx6/). Perhaps the values are not what you are expecting?

If you are using Chrome, you can use the built-in debugging tools to check out what's going on.

## Debugging Javascript in the Browser 101

- [Here is a primer on debugging with Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging).
- [Here is one for Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript).

In this case, I would try to figure out what the *real* value of `reponse` is, when you're trying to evaluate it. There are a few ways to do this:

### The value of `reponse`:

You should check to make sure your response is what you're expecting. Try these things out:

#### **`console.log()`**

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

This allows you to put a message into your browser's console. In this case, `console.log(reponse);` should be fine. From here you would see something like this:

[image]

Here you can see if `reponse.code_retour` is actually `-1` (as in the example) or something else.

#### `debugger` Keyword

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)

You can simply put the word `debugger;` somewhere in your code, and if you have the debugging tools (as described in the earlier links) open it pause the code at that instant. Here you can see what the real value of `reponse.code_retour` is.

[image]

Breakpoints are cool.

They let you essentially "pause time" by stopping the code at a particular moment, and you are free to move around here.

You can **skip forward**, **jump into**, and **jump out of** function scopes, with these buttons: [image]. All of this is probably explained in the earlier documents.

These are essentially breakpoints:

#### Breakpoints

You can also add "breakpoints" using the debugging tool built into your browser. Just go to the sources tab, and click the line number you want to stop at:

[image]

### The request data (form data)

You should check what you are sending to your server in the first place! It's possible the code isn't doing what you expect.

To do this, I'd recommend pulling out everything you are passing into `$.ajax`, and storing it in a separate variable (for example, `ajaxConfig`). Then, you can use one of the methods earlier to ensure the data you send to the server (`ajaxConfig.data`) is what you are expecting to send.

Example code:

```
var ajaxConfig = {
   type: 'POST',
   url: $('#url_for_ajax').val()+'/post_formulaire_responsables_personne',
   data: $('#form_responsable').serialize(),
   success: successCallback
};

// Here you can see exactly what you are sending to the server!
console.log("ajaxConfig: ", ajaxConfig.data);

$.ajax(ajaxConfig);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation Martin. I have undertstood my error : my json response was not correct. And with your post you helped a beginner. Merci.