# javascript get id value into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have used an api to get some information about someone who visits my page. The data is returned into a JSON format and I have used the .html function to set the content into some IDs like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function (data) {
    $("#lat").html(data.lat);
    $("#lon").html(data.lon);
});
```

Using:

```
<p id="lat"></p> 
<p id="lon"></p>
```

in my html body, I can see that the data has been set and is printed in my browser.

My question is how can I retrieve the data that is printed from the IDs into another, separate variable to continue to use/pass of to other functions ? I have tried using different functions like `getElementById()` etc. but none have worked.

Comment: why not just store `data.lat` and `data.lon` directly in a variable?

Comment: You want the html of an element by its id?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`$(element).html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html1) to *get* contents of an element.

For example:

```
var someHtml = "<p>Hello world!</p>";

$(someElement).html(someHtml); 
// This will set the html to be "<p>Hello world!</p>"

alert( $(someElement).html() );
// This will return "<p>Hello world!</p>" in the alert box!
```

To directly answer your question:

```
var coords = {
    // lat coord
    'lat' : $("#lat").html(),

    // long coord
    'lon' :$("#lon").html()
};
```

You can then reference them with `coords.lat` and `coords.lon`

## That being said!

There's really no reason to set the `coords` variable based on the HTML elements' values. Even if you have to display them, you'd be better off saving the variable directly from the API response to shave off some milliseconds.

So you might do this:

```
var coords = {};
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function (data) {
    $("#lat").html(data.lat);
    $("#lon").html(data.lon);
    coords = { 'lat' : data.lat, 'lon' : data.lon };
});
```

## Edit:

As per your [pastebin example](http://pastebin.com/JmxVbJ4D) - your error is coming from two places:

#### 1. You are trying to affect the `#map` div before it is rendered

Firstly, move all your scripts to be **below** your HTML, so you will have `<div id="map"></div>` right next to `<table id="GeoResults"></table>`

Lines 22-27 become:

```
<table id="GeoResults"></table>

<p id="lat"></p>
<p id="lon"></p>

<div id="map"></div>
```

#### 2. You are references `latitude` before it is set.

On lines 61 and 62 you try `console.log()` and `document.write()` to see the variable `latitude`. It is not defined until immediately after:

```
        console.log(latitude);
        document.write(latitude);

        var coords = {
            // lat coord
            'lat' : $("#lat").html(),

            // long coord
            'lon' :$("#lon").html()
        };
```

So that *obviously* won't work - just move those lines until after you define `latitude` and you're golden.

## [Try out the updated HTML](http://jsbin.com/gabohorixu/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have tried the .html() function like you said myself before posting this question and have tried it again now and unfortunately it doesn't work. I get an "undefined" when attempting to print the variable using document.write(coords.lat) or using the console.log(coords.lat).

Comment: Interesting, can you create us an example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ? Or provide more code?

Comment: @bf16 you used `console.log()` after you're sure `getJSON` was called? There's no reason it should fill the html elements and not save the variable

Comment: You might want to check out [my answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539268/why-this-condition-is-not-correct-in-js/35539636#35539636) which details how to debug variables.

Comment: Here's my full code: http://pastebin.com/JmxVbJ4D , I basically need to pass the lon and lat variables in the var city longitutde/latitude fields respectively

Comment: @mjr yes, I have used it after getJSON was called, I'm sure.

Comment: @bf16 I've updated my answer and provided the working snippet

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Moving the console/write stuff immediately after the var coords definition and then attempting to use console.out(coords.lat) or the document.write variant still gets me the same issue. Passing the coords.lat/lon into the var city afterwards cause the map to not render (obviously)